# Unable to create new folder on external drive due to I/O error (at the main HDD)

Tags: dual-boot, hard-drive

I get this message when I try to create a new folder.

> There was an error creating the directory in `/media/fahmy/New Volume`
>
> Error creating directory: Input/output error

[image]

I have Ubuntu 16.04 alongside Windows 10 and i have disabled the fastboot option on it.

Comment: Do you have permission to create directory in `/media/fahmy/New Volume`?

Comment: Yes i have all permissions

Comment: What is the nature of this directory? Is it part of CD/DVD, of USB flash, or remote share?

Comment: It's part of the HDD (Partition type: HPFS/NTFS)

Comment: Have you try to do the operation by hand?

Comment: Did you try to make the folder as a superuser? *sudo mkdir <folder name>* , sometimes NTFS partitions get mounted in read-only mode, check the output of *lsblk*

Comment: I don't know what you mean (by hand), i just trying to past some files or create folder but in vain

Comment: How did you prepare the drive and create the NTFS partition. Did you lay down a new partition table when you started? What does the SMART tools tell you? Depending on how you did the init, you may have a bad hard disk drive.

Answer (score 0):

You did not `properly shutdown` windows 10.

I get same error when I don't properly shutdown, the partition opens as `read only` file-system. any attempt to write Say's its a read-only file-system.

Comment: Sure you're right? It's "I/O Error"  not "No Permissions".

Comment: That's wrong. That only applies to a Windows C: drive that has not been properly prepared to work in a dual-boot configuration with Ubuntu... and it wouldn't throw an I/O error.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that your window machine is not shutdown properly, and it will not shutdown properly until you turn off the "**Fast StartUp**" option in window(which is by default turn on (selected) in window. Here are steps to do this:-

1. Power Option
2. System Settings
3. Down you will see the option of **Shutdown Settings**
4. Save changes.
   Hurray you are all set to go. Restart your machine and you are able to write the file(Open the folder and create file. For more info go ***here*** (https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4189-turn-off-fast-startup-windows-10-a.html)